# [Android]Downloading a youtube video

Tags: android, download, youtube

I am trying to Download a Video as explained in:

[Can’t download youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678051/cant-download-youtube-video)
and
[How does a YouTube movie downloader work? - YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172962/how-does-a-youtube-movie-downloader-work-youtube)

but it seems this method does not work anymore.

How can I download the .flv from Youtube today? Is there a method to save the movie after I watched it, without downloading again?
Does anybody have a working exmaple? (Is the best way to learn)

Thanks in advance, 
Adrian.

Comment: Are 3 steps: sorce code (html), decoding the url and download the stream. Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203047/code-for-download-video-from-youtube-on-java-android/9497608#9497608

Answer (score 0):

Userscripts.org has some scripts that enable downloading and viewing without flash. I haven't tried it, but OilCan is supposed to run Greasemonkey scripts on Android.