# Code for download video from Youtube on Java, Android

Tags: java, android, youtube

I created code for download video from Youtube, but this code doesn't work with Wi-fi connection and work with mobile connection. Where did I have mistake?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private class ReceivingDataFromYoutube extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        private String result;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            int begin, end;
            String tmpstr = null;
            try {
                URL url=new URL("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y12-1miZHLs&nomobile=1");
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                InputStream stream=con.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(stream);
                StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
                char[] buf=new char[262144];                
                int chars_read;
                while ((chars_read = reader.read(buf, 0, 262144)) != -1) {
                    buffer.append(buf, 0, chars_read);
                }
                tmpstr=buffer.toString();

                begin  = tmpstr.indexOf("url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=");
                end = tmpstr.indexOf("&", begin + 27);
                if (end == -1) {
                    end = tmpstr.indexOf("\"", begin + 27);
                }
                tmpstr = UtilClass.URLDecode(tmpstr.substring(begin + 27, end));

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            Vector url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = new Vector();
            begin = 0;
            end   = tmpstr.indexOf(",");

            while (end != -1) {
                url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.addElement(tmpstr.substring(begin, end));
                begin = end + 1;
                end   = tmpstr.indexOf(",", begin);
            }

            url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.addElement(tmpstr.substring(begin, tmpstr.length()));
            String result = "";
            Enumeration url_encoded_fmt_stream_map_enum = url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.elements();
            while (url_encoded_fmt_stream_map_enum.hasMoreElements()) {
                tmpstr = (String)url_encoded_fmt_stream_map_enum.nextElement();
                begin = tmpstr.indexOf("itag=");
                if (begin != -1) {
                    end = tmpstr.indexOf("&", begin + 5);

                    if (end == -1) {
                          end = tmpstr.length();
                    }

                    int fmt = Integer.parseInt(tmpstr.substring(begin + 5, end));

                    if (fmt == 35) {
                        begin = tmpstr.indexOf("url=");
                        if (begin != -1) {
                            end = tmpstr.indexOf("&", begin + 4);
                            if (end == -1) {
                               end = tmpstr.length();
                            }
                            result = UtilClass.URLDecode(tmpstr.substring(begin + 4, end));
                            this.result=result;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }         
            try {
              URL u = new URL(result);
              HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
              c.setRequestMethod("GET");
/*              c.setRequestProperty("Youtubedl-no-compression", "True");
              c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "YouTube");*/

              c.setDoOutput(true);
              c.connect();

              FileOutputStream f=new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/3.flv"));

              InputStream in=c.getInputStream();
              byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
              int sz = 0;
              while ( (sz = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                   f.write(buffer,0, sz);
              }
              f.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                new RuntimeException();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                new RuntimeException();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }    

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new ReceivingDataFromYoutube().execute();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hii can you share how you solve this ? How to download youtube video ?

Comment: @Денис Нагибин hey can u pls tell how it works because i want now how it works..i just copy your code but it give error on "UtilClass".

Comment: whats this UtilClass.URLDecode()is in ur function can u explain.. i dint get it

Comment: Dude, you've written UtilClass. would you like to share that class?

Comment: can you answer my that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398325/downloading-youtube-video-in-android

Answer (score 27, accepted):

3 steps:

1. Check the source code (HTML) of YouTube, you'll get the link like this `http%253A%252F%252Fo-o.preferred.telemar-cnf1.v18.lscache6.c.youtube.com%252Fvideoplayback ...`
2. Decode the url (remove the codes `%2B`, `%25`, etc), [create a decoder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) with the codes and use the function `Uri.decode(url)` to replace invalid escaped octets
3. Use the code to download stream:

```java
        URL u = null;
        InputStream is = null;  
        
        try {
            u = new URL(url);
            is = u.openStream(); 
            HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection(); //to know the size of video
            int size = huc.getContentLength();                 
 
            if(huc != null) {
                String fileName = "FILE.mp4";
                String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File f = new File(storagePath,fileName);
               
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                if(is != null) {
                    while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        fos.write(buffer,0, len1);  
                    }
                }
                if(fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            }                       
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {               
                if(is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // just going to ignore this one
            }
        }
```

That's all, most of stuff you'll find on the web!!!

Comment: Really worked for me @Денис Нагибин. I have a private app only to download youtube videos on my phone.

Comment: This method doesnt work anymore. Could you have a look at it and update it?

Comment: @SilvioGuedes hey is this working because i downloaded file very easily but when i am going to play it show me error "You Can't Play Video".

Comment: @SilvioGuedes hey, thanx for ur reply but i am talking about in my application not others app.so this not perfect answer.

Comment: it just download a file of 108 KB and it cant be played. huc.getContentLength();  returns -1 always.

Comment: @Silvio Guedes, Is there any good source for doing first step?
I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240011/get-the-download-url-for-youtube-video-android-java
this, but It cannot be applied all videos.

Comment: how to check the sorce code (HTML) of YouTube  for example for this video what will be the  url:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AK9BPC5Qosc

Comment: dude, can you share your work code or can you answer my that question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398325/downloading-youtube-video-in-android

Comment: @SilvioGuedes can you explain implementation of you first step?

Comment: Help me plz,I have extracted the exact url from youtube but not able to download because youtube is banned in our country.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832939/use-proxy-for-downloading-mp4-videos

Comment: sir any idea how download video specific Quality

Answer (score 4):

Ref : [Youtube Video Download (Android/Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588551/youtube-video-download-android-java/52588588#52588588)

```
private static final HashMap<String, Meta> typeMap = new HashMap<String, Meta>();
```

**initTypeMap(); call first**

```
class Meta {
    public String num;
    public String type;
    public String ext;

    Meta(String num, String ext, String type) {
        this.num = num;
        this.ext = ext;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Video {
    public String ext = "";
    public String type = "";
    public String url = "";

    Video(String ext, String type, String url) {
        this.ext = ext;
        this.type = type;
        this.url = url;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Video> getStreamingUrisFromYouTubePage(String ytUrl)
        throws IOException {
    if (ytUrl == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Remove any query params in query string after the watch?v=<vid> in
    // e.g.
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RUPACpf8Vs&feature=youtube_gdata_player
    int andIdx = ytUrl.indexOf('&');
    if (andIdx >= 0) {
        ytUrl = ytUrl.substring(0, andIdx);
    }

    // Get the HTML response
    /* String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1)";*/
   /* HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
            userAgent);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(ytUrl);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);*/
    String html = "";
    HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(ytUrl).openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();
    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        str.append(line.replace("\\u0026", "&"));
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();

    // Parse the HTML response and extract the streaming URIs
    if (html.contains("verify-age-thumb")) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "YouTube is asking for age verification. We can't handle that sorry.");
        return null;
    }

    if (html.contains("das_captcha")) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Captcha found, please try with different IP address.");
        return null;
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("stream_map\":\"(.*?)?\"");
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/stream_map=(.[^&]*?)\"/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group());
    }

    if (matches.size() != 1) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Found zero or too many stream maps.");
        return null;
    }

    String urls[] = matches.get(0).split(",");
    HashMap<String, String> foundArray = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String ppUrl : urls) {
        String url = URLDecoder.decode(ppUrl, "UTF-8");
        Log.e("URL","URL : "+url);

        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("itag=([0-9]+?)[&]");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(url);
        String itag = null;
        if (m1.find()) {
            itag = m1.group(1);
        }

        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("signature=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(url);
        String sig = null;
        if (m2.find()) {
            sig = m2.group(1);
        } else {
            Pattern p23 = Pattern.compile("signature&s=(.*?)[&]");
            Matcher m23 = p23.matcher(url);
            if (m23.find()) {
                sig = m23.group(1);
            }
        }

        Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("url=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(ppUrl);
        String um = null;
        if (m3.find()) {
            um = m3.group(1);
        }

        if (itag != null && sig != null && um != null) {
            Log.e("foundArray","Adding Value");
            foundArray.put(itag, URLDecoder.decode(um, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + "signature=" + sig);
        }
    }
    Log.e("foundArray","Size : "+foundArray.size());
    if (foundArray.size() == 0) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't find any URLs and corresponding signatures");
        return null;
    }


    ArrayList<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();

    for (String format : typeMap.keySet()) {
        Meta meta = typeMap.get(format);

        if (foundArray.containsKey(format)) {
            Video newVideo = new Video(meta.ext, meta.type,
                    foundArray.get(format));
            videos.add(newVideo);
            Log.d("Downloader", "YouTube Video streaming details: ext:" + newVideo.ext
                    + ", type:" + newVideo.type + ", url:" + newVideo.url);
        }
    }

    return videos;
}

private class YouTubePageStreamUriGetter extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Video>> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(webViewActivity.this, "",
                "Connecting to YouTube...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Video> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<Video> fVideos = new ArrayList<>();
        String url = params[0];
        try {
            ArrayList<Video> videos = getStreamingUrisFromYouTubePage(url);
            /*                Log.e("Downloader","Size of Video : "+videos.size());*/
            if (videos != null && !videos.isEmpty()) {
                for (Video video : videos)
                {
                    Log.e("Downloader", "ext : " + video.ext);
                    if (video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("mp4") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("3gp") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("flv") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("webm")) {
                        ext = video.ext.toLowerCase();
                        fVideos.add(new Video(video.ext,video.type,video.url));
                    }
                }


                return fVideos;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't get YouTube streaming URL", e);
        }
        Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't get stream URI for " + url);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Video> streamingUrl) {
        super.onPostExecute(streamingUrl);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (streamingUrl != null) {
            if (!streamingUrl.isEmpty()) {
                //Log.e("Steaming Url", "Value : " + streamingUrl);

                for (int i = 0; i < streamingUrl.size(); i++) {
                    Video fX = streamingUrl.get(i);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "URL : " + fX.url);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "TYPE : " + fX.type);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "EXT : " + fX.ext);
                }
                //new ProgressBack().execute(new String[]{streamingUrl, filename + "." + ext});
            }
        }
    }
}
public void initTypeMap()
{
    typeMap.put("13", new Meta("13", "3GP", "Low Quality - 176x144"));
    typeMap.put("17", new Meta("17", "3GP", "Medium Quality - 176x144"));
    typeMap.put("36", new Meta("36", "3GP", "High Quality - 320x240"));
    typeMap.put("5", new Meta("5", "FLV", "Low Quality - 400x226"));
    typeMap.put("6", new Meta("6", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("34", new Meta("34", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("35", new Meta("35", "FLV", "High Quality - 854x480"));
    typeMap.put("43", new Meta("43", "WEBM", "Low Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("44", new Meta("44", "WEBM", "Medium Quality - 854x480"));
    typeMap.put("45", new Meta("45", "WEBM", "High Quality - 1280x720"));
    typeMap.put("18", new Meta("18", "MP4", "Medium Quality - 480x360"));
    typeMap.put("22", new Meta("22", "MP4", "High Quality - 1280x720"));
    typeMap.put("37", new Meta("37", "MP4", "High Quality - 1920x1080"));
    typeMap.put("33", new Meta("38", "MP4", "High Quality - 4096x230"));
}
```

**Edit 2:**

> Some time This Code Not worked proper

**Same-origin policy**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

```
problem of Same-origin policy. Essentially, you cannot download this file from www.youtube.com because they are different domains. A workaround of this problem is [CORS][1].
```

Ref : https://superuser.com/questions/773719/how-do-all-of-these-save-video-from-youtube-services-work/773998#773998

```
url_encoded_fmt_stream_map // traditional: contains video and audio stream
adaptive_fmts              // DASH: contains video or audio stream
```

Each of these is a comma separated array of what I would call "stream objects". Each "stream object" will contain values like this

```
url  // direct HTTP link to a video
itag // code specifying the quality
s    // signature, security measure to counter downloading
```

Each URL will be encoded so you will need to decode them. Now the tricky part.

YouTube has at least 3 security levels for their videos

```
unsecured // as expected, you can download these with just the unencoded URL
s         // see below
RTMPE     // uses "rtmpe://" protocol, no known method for these
```

The RTMPE videos are typically used on official full length movies, and are protected with SWF Verification Type 2. This has been around since 2011 and has yet to be reverse engineered.

The type "s" videos are the most difficult that can actually be downloaded. You will typcially see these on VEVO videos and the like. They start with a signature such as

AA5D05FA7771AD4868BA4C977C3DEAAC620DE020E.0F421820F42978A1F8EAFCDAC4EF507DB5
Then the signature is scrambled with a function like this

```
function mo(a) {
  a = a.split("");
  a = lo.rw(a, 1);
  a = lo.rw(a, 32);
  a = lo.IC(a, 1);
  a = lo.wS(a, 77);
  a = lo.IC(a, 3);
  a = lo.wS(a, 77);
  a = lo.IC(a, 3);
  a = lo.wS(a, 44);
  return a.join("")
}
```

This function is dynamic, it typically changes every day. To make it more difficult the function is hosted at a URL such as

http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-en_US-vflycBCEX.js

this introduces the problem of Same-origin policy. Essentially, you cannot download this file from www.youtube.com because they are different domains. A workaround of this problem is CORS. With CORS, s.ytimg.com could add this header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.youtube.com
```

and it would allow the JavaScript to download from www.youtube.com. Of course they do not do this. A workaround for this workaround is to use a CORS proxy. This is a proxy that responds with the following header to all requests

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So, now that you have proxied your JS file, and used the function to scramble the signature, you can use that in the querystring to download a video.