# How to download Youtube video in android SD card programmatically

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have YouTube link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySuYTKkgIvg"

How can I store this video from YouTube to my SD card?

I can play video using YouTube player by android YouTube DATA API but don't know how to download it
is any API / code who can help me to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9497608

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySuYTKkgIvg 
this link can be use for downloading in code which u refer me though ur link @Sreekanthss ur code shows how to dowload my problem is i dont know how to get that streaming link from above mentioned link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Youtube API** allows you to search & list videos and obtain the **mediaplayer URL**, so that you can play **videos** within your web page.

**[Look here for downloading video from Youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203047/code-for-download-video-from-youtube-on-java-android)**

[Youtube Video Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api)

[Youtube Java Data API - Getting Started](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/getting-started-with-youtube-java-api.html)

It does not allow you to download the byte content of videos - because Google is protecting their own rights and the rights of the content creators.

[Youtube Google API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms)

Comment: What if I have a channel and want videos to be downloaded, will it be still unavailable?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **my library**, *[youtube-dl-android](https://github.com/bawaviki/youtube-dl-android)*, which lets you to easily extract video link from 1000+ sites including YouTube, Facebook, etc.

Step 1: Add jitpack repository to your project build file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bawaviki.youtube-dl-android:library:0.7.+'
}
```

Step 3: Use *Youtube-dl* instance

```
YoutubeDLRequest request = new YoutubeDLRequest("http://youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx");
request.setOption("-o", youtubeDLDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/%(title)s.%(ext)s");
YoutubeDL.getInstance().execute(request, (progress, etaInSeconds) -> {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(progress) + "% (ETA " + String.valueOf(etaInSeconds) + " seconds)");
});
```