# How does youtube downloader works?

Tags: download, youtube

There are many similar questions like this but there is no really a working answer but there are some API present for that. But there is no clear answer about how it is done( like how to find the link of the video file and download it). Most of the questions are for C# in the website.

So,can anyone explain how it is done so that it can be implemented in any language.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172962/how-does-a-youtube-movie-downloader-work-youtube) but I cant do it properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Youtube changes there mp4 url location and markup on a regular basis to stop downloaders from easily finding the links.  The link can always be found again after (downside of html) but it changes all the time,  In general though you scrape the page and look for the URL, from that point downloading it is very easy if you actually know how to write code